# Doughnut with rounded edges can be implemented in Maui?

Tags: maui, syncfusion-chart

I created a donut chart with Syncfusion in a Maui application and I want it to have rounded edges.
I want it to look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBAMx.png)

But currently is looking like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGCPa.png)

This is what I've tried:

```
<chart:SfCircularChart >
            <chart:DoughnutSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"         
                InnerRadius="0.7"         
                XBindingPath="Product"
                YBindingPath="SalesRate"
                PaletteBrushes="{StaticResource Colors}">
            </chart:DoughnutSeries>
        </chart:SfCircularChart>
```

This style can be implemented in Maui with Syncfusion?

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  Generally you should post enough relevant code to illustrate what you are doing or have tried to do

Comment: `Ask SyncFusion support.` I do see in the code snippet in [Doughnut Charts, section Center Hole Size](https://help.syncfusion.com/maui/circular-charts/doughnutchart#center-hole-size), `... <Border.StrokeShape> <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="200"/> ...`, which adds some shading on the inside edge of the doughnut. But its unclear whether the full effect you seek is supported.